# Drush from GitHub stopped working

Tags: drush

I have a [Github clone of drush](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush) that has been working since it moved there.  I did a `git pull` this morning, and am now getting errors:

> $ drush
>
> Warning: require(/home/mpd/drush/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/mpd/drush/includes/bootstrap.inc on line 1007
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   '/home/mpd/drush/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:') in
>   /home/mpd/drush/includes/bootstrap.inc on line 1007

How can I fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undefined error: 0 OR Unable to load autoload.php. Drush now requires Composer](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/105828/undefined-error-0-or-unable-to-load-autoload-php-drush-now-requires-composer)

Comment: Don't agree with the dup.  It's a totally different error.  I posted this question a day to two after the composer change and asked Greg to write a canonical response to it to prevent lots of similar questions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Drush now uses [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) for managing external libraries.  You can read about this in the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/pull/127).

If you don't have composer installed, you can [follow the instructions](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md) on its project page.  Under Linux or OSX, you can do

```
$ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
$ mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

which will install it globally.

Once you have done this, you can

```
$ cd /path/to/your/git/clone/of/drush
$ composer install
```

This will download all of the external depencencies, and drush should start working.

See the [drush project page](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush) for details.

Comment: This should totally be in the README.md (composer install)!! Very helpful!