# How to Install two version of Drush?

Tags: drush

I installed in my PC drush 8 for develop on Drupal 8, but I need drush 7 for connect with my sites on remote servers.
I download manually [drush 7](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/archive/7.x.zip) but when I try to open said me:

> Unable to load autoload.php. Drush now requires Composer in order to
>   install its dependencies and autoload classes. Please see README.md

Then, How I install two versions of Drush in my PC?

Comment: Have you seen README.md?

Comment: @Mołot yes, but the only options what i found was install with composer and then it, update the version from `dev` to `7.x`, not allow two versions, I think.

Comment: If you want to install different versions of Drush I recommend you try [this tutorial](http://www.jpstacey.info/blog/2014-04-07/switching-between-drush-major-versions.html) (for me it's a very clear way to do it), and for aliasing check out [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-migrate-and-sync-drupal-sites-with-drush).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Drush from GitHub stopped working](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/102940/drush-from-github-stopped-working)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Having multiple Drush instances for different core versions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/267511/having-multiple-drush-instances-for-different-core-versions)

Answer (score 2):

Drush 8 should work just fine with remote sites running Drush 7.

To get around the error message you are seeing, run `composer install` from the Drush directory.

If you want to install multiple versions of Drush to run locally, the easiest way to do it is to manage your Drupal site with Composer, and add a 'require drush' line in your composer.json.  If your global Drush is at least version 7, then you will find that Drush automatically dispatches to the site-local Drush whenever you target it.

One really good use-case for doing this would be to run Drush 7 stable as your global Drush, but use Drush 8 with any Drupal 8 site.

See also:

https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project
https://github.com/pantheon-systems/example-drupal7-composer

Comment: Thank you @greg_1_anderson When I run `drush @server.dev status` I got `/bin/bash: drush8: command not found`.

Comment: Did you set `%drush-script` to `drush8` in your alias file?  By default, Drush should try to run `drush` on the remote server.  Whatever script name is used will need to be in your $PATH on the remote site.  Make sure that you set your $PATH at the top of your .bashrc file; a lot of distro's exit early, near the top of .bashrc when called in non-interactive mode, which can prevent Drush backend invoke from being able to find the remote Drush executable.

Comment: Ups... the drush versions on the server is 6.6.0 :(